# How to check if a PHP session is set using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have a php application that is working alongside jquery. 
I want to check if the user session is still available in the js function.

If a session is set or if not return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways, if the file is a .php ext. then:

`var something = "<?php = $_SESSION['something'] ?>";`

If you print the file after `file_get_contents()` use `str_replace`

You also can check cookie in javascript, seach for `PHPSESSID`

Answer (score 4):

Check if a cookie named `PHPSESSID` exists.

This will fail if you changed the name of the session cookie from the default (in which case you just check for the cookie name you specified), or if the session cookie has been set to `httpOnly` (which it should have been for safety reasons).